# How to interact with this kind of datatype

Tags: haskell

I have a datatype which is defined as:

```
data DType = DT List Int
```

Since it's neither a tuple, a list, or anything else which looks like I'm used to in other languages, I'm a bit confused as to how I should interact with it. I'd very much appreciate a simple example.

Comment: Through pattern matching, so `f (DT mylist myint) = ...` with `...` an expression with `mylist` and `myint`.

Comment: Thanks, that format was all I needed!

Comment: What is `List`? I assume it's something like `data List = ...` itself, but I'm used to that word being used in a context like `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)`, so I keep wanting to read `DType` as a wrapper around a `List Int` value.

Comment: You said it is not a tuple but it is, in a sense. The type `DType` is essentially the same as `(List, Int)`, the difference being syntactic. The values of each type are of the form `DT xs n` and  `(xs, n)` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Willem above:

Through pattern matching, so `f (DT mylist myint) = ...` with `...` an expression with mylist and myint